# if statement in netbeans is not giving the right output

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make the user enter a 5 digit number but the number should be a binary number.

I separated each number and did the if statement on each one so it only can be a zero or one. But when I enter a binary number it's still saying wrong number.

[image: picture to help find the solution]

I tried to put `!(d1==0)` ... and `(d1 != 0)` and it didn't work well in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Change the OR to AND, the logic you're using is always going to give you wrong number. For example:

```
if (d1 != 0 && d1 != 1)...
```

Otherwhise it will always fail because 1 is different than 0 and viceversa...

Comment: thank you for that ! but now its not putting wrong number when I'm entering a digit that is different then 1 or zero :S

Comment: @mariochakar: With all those nested ifs, you're only going to output anything if *all* of the conditions are met, in other words if *none* of the characters is correct.

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried putting them all in one if like that 

if(((d1 != 0) && (d1 != 1)) && ((d2 != 0) && (d2 != 1)) && ((d3 != 0) && (d3 != 1)) && ((d4 != 0) && (d4 != 1)) && ((d5 != 0) && (d5 != 1)))
        System.out.println(+number+" is not valid");

still didn't work

Comment: You need to think more carefully about and Vs or. Try to get it working with two digits first.